# Does GitLab's API provide a way to create issues based on issue templates?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm building a Python tool that can use GitLab issue templates to create issues. Does the API provide a way to do so?

I read the documentation and it seems not but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I can only find "[Using a URL with prefilled values](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#using-a-url-with-prefilled-values)", where the following URL is using a [description template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html)

```
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new?
  issue[title]=Validate%20new%20concept&
  issuable_template=Feature%20Proposal%20-%20basic
```

Calling that URL in your Python tool would use said template.

Comment: Thank you for your help it's not exactly what I wanted to do. I wanted the issue to be created by the script, not a link to the issue creation page that has its fields prefilled

Comment: @kurisukun But the script could call the URL in order to trigger the issue creation, could it not?